# Matplotlib: increase distance between automatically generated tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

When generating a new figure or axis with matplotlib (or pyplot), there is (I assume) some sort of automated way to determine how many ticks are appropriate for each axis.

Unfortunately, this often results in labels which are too close to be read comfortably, or even overlap. I'm aware of the ways to specify tick locations and labels explicitly (e.g. `ax.set_xticks`, `ax.set_xtick_labels`, but I wonder if whatever does the automatic tick distribution if nothing is specified can be influenced by some global matplotlib parameter(s).

**Do such global parameters exist, and what are they?**

I'm generating lots of figures automatically and save them, and it can get a little annoying having to treat them all individually ...

In case there is no simple way to tell matplotlib to thin out the labels, is there some other workaround to achieve more generous spacing between them?

Comment: Can you change the image size to tailor the tick labels? I mean if your image is 5x5, and your fixed labels number is 100, but if you make the image of 20x20, that will automatically increase the distance right?

Comment: You can easily change the default number of ticks for an axes via `ax.locator_params(axis="x", nbins=3)`. But there is no globale parameter for that. The only global option would be to monkey-patch the `AutoLocator` with your own logic.

Comment: @ernest: thanks. I had seen the nbins argument, but that requires me to know beforehand how many labels will have space on the axis, which I don't, since the size of labels depends on how many decimals are required, i.e. on the data itself ...

Comment: You can likely come up with a decent estimate of nbins based on how wide your axes are and how long your tick labels tend to be.  In general though it’s a hard problem.

Answer (score 0):

by reading the documentation of xticks [matplotlib.pyplot.xticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) there seems to be no such global arguments.
However it is very simple to get around it by using the explicit `xticks` and `xticks_labels` taking into account that you can:

- change the font size (decrease it)
- rotate the labels (by 45°) or make them vertical (less overlapping).
- increase the fig size.
- program a function that generates adaptif `xticks` based on your input.

and many other possible workarounds.

Comment: Those possibilities are all things I've come across before, and I've used several already but the challange is to have something that works automatically, not only after I look at a particular figure and find that the spacing is too tight. Also: I need to have fairly large fonts compared to figure size because the figures need to be legible in presentations, also with crappy projectors.